# RcppArmadillo returns pinv(): svd failed

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, armadillo, rcpparmadillo

I have a matrix A and a vector b, I want to solve the linear system Ax = b for x. The problem is that frequently A will be singular. I used RcppArmadillo package in R to do this. Basically I do

```
arma::mat A = something;
arma::vec b = something;
arma::mat tmp_pinv = arma::pinv(X, 0.001);
arma::mat tmp_res = tmp_pinv * b;
```

However, I got error message "pinv(): svd failed". Is there any way to solve this? Either I can maybe use different package? Or I can try catch this error and let the problem keeps going? Any thoughts?

Comment: Inverting `A` is pretty much the worst approach you can choose (from a numerical perspective) if you want to solve `Ax = b`. Use a better approach.

Comment: Seconding what @Roland said.  In particular, Armadillo has the `solve()` function which I use in the [OLS example `fastLm()` in the RcppArmadillo package](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/master/src/fastLm.cpp).

Answer (score 0):

If the solution can be approximate, one approach is to iteratively add a small scalar to the diagonal of A to make the matrix non-singular and keep retrying to find the solution.

The [solve()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#solve) function is generally more robust and efficient than [pinv()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#pinv) for solving linear systems.

```
arma::mat A = something;
arma::vec b = something;
arma::mat tmp_res;

bool done = arma::solve(tmp_res,A,b);
int iter = 0;

while(!done) {
  A.diag() += 100.0 * arma::datum::eps;
  done = arma::solve(tmp_res,A,b);
  if(iter > 1000)  break;  // give up when maximum number of iterations is reached
  iter++;
  }
```